# Error when trying to use vehicle tracking in Veins via TraCI Interface to SUMO

Tags: omnet++

I am using **Veins3.0** with **SUMO-0.21.0** and **omnetpp4.4**.
I tried to use the *vehicle tracking* command in **TraCI/SUMO**. It is described here: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_GUI_State. 
There you can read that the `Variable   View ID     Type of the value   New Value` for this command are `0xa6 "View #0" string <vehicle id>`.
 So I wrote a new function in `TraCICommandInterface.cc` to track a vehicle.

```
void TraCICommandInterface::setVehicleTracking(std::string nodeId) {
    uint8_t variableId = VAR_TRACK_VEHICLE;
    uint8_t variableType = TYPE_STRING;
    TraCIBuffer buf = connection.query(CMD_SET_GUI_VARIABLE, TraCIBuffer() << variableId << "View #0" << variableType << nodeId);
    ASSERT(buf.eof());
}
```

I used some constants from `TraCIConstants.h`

```
// track vehicle
#define VAR_TRACK_VEHICLE 0xa6
// command: set GUI variable
#define CMD_SET_GUI_VARIABLE 0xcc
// 8 bit ASCII string
#define TYPE_STRING 0x0C
```

The function is called from `TraCIMobility.h`, which fills the node id with `getExternalID()`.

```
    void commandTrackVehicle(){
        getCommandInterface()->setVehicleTracking(getExternalId());
    }
```

The error occurs when I call `commandTrackVehicle()` from the vehicle module with `mobility->commandTrackVehicle();`.

The error text in SUMO is:

```
error: tcpip::Storage::readIsSafe: want to read 1717063210 byte from Storage, but only 12 remaining
```

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this problem or to get more information about the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work if you change `TraCIBuffer() << "View #0"` to `TraCIBuffer() << std::string("View #0")`.

The reason is a bit complex:

SUMO's TraCI API [defines](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Protocol#Data_types) its data type `string` as

> 32 bit string length, followed by text coded as 8 bit ASCII

Veins 3 has [an overload for sending std::string](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIBuffer.cc#L44) as a TraCI-compatible string. It does not have one for a pointer-to-byte(s) data type (`char*`). That is, if you insert a `char*` (which is what `"View #0"` is to the compiler) into a Veins 3 `TraCIBuffer`, it won't know to apply this special formatting, confusing SUMO by sending a Byte (that it tries to interpret as a 32 bit length, followed by trying to read as many Bytes as the "length" indicates, and failing).